# UK passport expiring, can I use US passport instead if resident in UK?

Tags: passports

My son has both UK and US passports. We live in the UK. We are due to go away next week to Spain or Greece (uncooked yet) and I have just realised his UK passport expires in October. If he travels on his US passport will there be a problem re-entering the UK as he does not have any residency visas etc.? His Mum has a US passport with an indefinite leave to remain visa and I (Dad) only have UK passport. And I have just found I cannot do a same day renewal for a child’s passport..

Comment: As the answer to the other question notes, a British citizen can enter the UK on an expired passport. He should bring both passports with him. If he were only a British citizen, he would obviously have trouble leaving the UK since the airline wouldn't let him on the plane, but his US passport solves this problem.

Comment: @CGCampbell I tend to avoid answering questions which I believe are duplicates, since my understanding is that you shouldn't answer duplicate questions. Since the duplicate message can be a bit impersonal, I often add a comment to help explain how the question applies to theirs. I'm aware that answering in comments is discouraged, but claiming credit for an answer which someone else gave seems worse to me.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're planning on returning before or after the UK passport expires in October. If after then you should perhaps be more concerned about getting into trouble in Spain/Greece.

Comment: @PeterTaylor and if before then why ask the question?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. this has helped. I agree that leaving is ok as he has the US passport - and the airline would not let him board with a UK one with only 2 months left. The fact he can re-enter the UK on an expired UK passport, or one with on,y 2 months left on it, is new information to me and seems to fill the gap. Many thanks again..

Comment: @GaryBristow why would the airline not let him board with only 2 months left?  Greece and the UK are both in the EU, for now at least.  The only requirement is that the passport be valid during the entire trip, and maybe not even that: Try for example at https://www.traveldoc.aero; you'll see that the passport can even expire on the day of *departure,* though I personally wouldn't want to try that.

Comment: @phoog - thanks again, you’re right of course.. I’ve spent a long time travelling almost exclusively to the US or with my wife and her US passport, and I’d forgotten the convenience with our European ones.